# C# XML Reader how to tell if moved to next element?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have a system which allows the user to import a spreadsheet, which then gets made into an XML format. This spreadsheet is dynamic.

Each row of the spreadsheet is an element in the XML.

For example this spreadsheet as 3 rows:

```
<DocumentElement>
   <Person>
      <Title />
      <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
      <Surname>Smith</Surname>
      <eMail>example@example.com</eMail>
      <PostCode>AA11 2BB</PostCode>
      <Company></Company>
      <TelephoneNumber>01111111111</TelephoneNumber>
      <AddressLine1 />
      <AddressLine2 />
      <AddressLine3 />
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <Title />
      <FirstName>Simon</FirstName>
      <Surname>Long</Surname>
      <eMail>example@example.com</eMail>
      <PostCode>AA11 2BB</PostCode>
      <Company></Company>
      <TelephoneNumber>01111111111</TelephoneNumber>
      <AddressLine1 />
      <AddressLine2 />
      <AddressLine3 />
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <Title />
      <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
      <Surname>Boon</Surname>
      <eMail>example@example.com</eMail>
      <PostCode>AA11 2BB</PostCode>
      <Company></Company>
      <TelephoneNumber>01111111111</TelephoneNumber>
      <AddressLine1 />
      <AddressLine2 />
      <AddressLine3 />
   </Person>
</DocumentElement>
```

Each of these rows then gets made into a Person Class. However, i need to know when the XMLReader has moved to the next element in the XML, so i can then make a new class for for the next row.

So to end with i should have a person class for:
Tom Smith Person class, 
Simon Long Person class and 
Paul Book Person class

So, how can i tell if the XML reader is about to move to the next element so i can then make a new class?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `XmlReader` directly at all? `XmlSerializer` looks like the right tool for the job.  Declare some classes:

```
[XmlRoot("DocumentElement")]
public class DocumentElement : List<Person>
{
}

public class Person
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise your data:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentElement));

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"path\to\file.xml"))
{
    var doc = (DocumentElement) serializer.Deserialize(reader);            
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vh3jin) for a working demo.

Comment: Cannot use a class as the fields are dynamic.

Comment: So what does *Each of these rows then gets made into a Person Class* actually mean, then?

Answer (score 0):

NextSibling is the Key ;-)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("persons.xml");

XmlNode currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
Console.WriteLine("First person...");
Console.WriteLine(currNode.OuterXml);

XmlNode nextNode = currNode.NextSibling;
Console.WriteLine("\r\nSecond person...");
Console.WriteLine(nextNode.OuterXml);
```

Comment: Doesn't nextsibling simply get the node immediately following this node?

How would i know that the xmlread has finished processing the current node?

Comment: @user2183216 that's not relevant in this case, `XmlDocument` has created, read, and disposed of an `XmlReader` internally during `Load` - all of the XML is now in the DOM in memory. As an aside, if you're going to go the DOM route then LINQ to XML is preferable to `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really answering your question, but is an alternative method of selecting all of the 'Person' nodes.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load("persons.xml");
 XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Person");
```

This returns all the nodes anywhere in your document with the name "Person".

You could then iterate over this list of nodes and use the information to create your classes.

It would also save you the trouble of navigating around the document finding "Person" elements.

Comment: How would i know it's finished processing the 1 Person before moving to the next Person?

Comment: so the SelectNodes returns a list of XmlNodes.  With each XmlNode you can do whatever processing you were doing on the data.  E.g.:

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Person"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.FirstChild());
    // Or whatever
}

You don't need to navigate around the XML to find the Person nodes - you just have to navigate to the data inside the nodes you get back from SelectNodes to get whatever data you want.